# I am making an autoclicker, and I need to customize it to click only when I hold left click

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

```
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is: It keeps clicking, so the program continues, and it doesn't stop clicking. I was wondering why and how to fix it.

Comment: @Blaze `GetAsyncKeyState` should return false if the mouse isn't pressed.

Comment: well, how can i fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if ((GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000) != 0)
```

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate:

> Although the least significant bit of the return value indicates whether the key has been pressed since the last query, due to the pre-emptive multitasking nature of Windows, another application can call GetAsyncKeyState and receive the "recently pressed" bit instead of your application. The behavior of the least significant bit of the return value is retained strictly for compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications (which are non-preemptive) and should not be relied upon.